# Gitlab CODEOWNERS to automatically add approvers

Tags: gitlab

I love GitLab, but I am frustrated to assign approvers manually for each Merge Request. Gitlab friendly suggest to `Tip: add a CODEOWNERS to automatically add approvers based on file paths and file types.` And so I did , I have created a file under : `.gitlab/docs/CODEOWNERS.txt`
Here is the contents of my file :

> ## Multiple codeowners can be specified, separated by whitespace
>
> CODEOWNERS @eduardo.baiao   @n.belokopytov  @viacheslav.iankovyi    @yan.braslavsky

But unfortunately it does not auto assigns reviewers during Merge Requests. Did I do something wrong ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 6):

Assigning approvers based on a `CODEOWNERS` file requires either GitLab **Premium** or GitLab **Silver** (or higher).

- According to the [Code Owners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_owners.html) documentation, the `CODEOWNERS` file should be placed in either .gitlab/ *or* docs/ *or* the root directory. I don't think it will find it in .gitlab/docs.
- Additionally, the docs specify that the file should be named `CODEOWNERS`, not `CODEOWNERS.txt`. Try removing the .txt extension and see if it works.
- Make sure that you have "Require approval from code owners" enabled in Settings -> General -> Merge Request Approvals. [Merge Request Approvals](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html#code-owners-approvals-premium)

Comment: Note that "Require approval from code owners" has been moved to Settings -> Repository -> Protected Branches.

Comment: Even if I have all the listed requirements fulfilled and the relevant code owners are correctly and automatically listed in merge requests, they are still not auto-assigned to be reviewers.

Answer (score 2):

[GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#define-default-owners-for-codeowners-sections) (March 2023) might help (still for Premium or Ultimate only)

> ### Define default owners for CODEOWNERS sections
>
> Define a default code owner for each section of your `CODEOWNERS` file.
> This default now applies to files and directories referenced in the section. This way, you don’t have to repeat the same owners over and over.
> Individual files and directories can still be overridden.
>
> In this example, all files and directories are owned by `@dev-team`, except `README.md` and the `data-models/` directory.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_10/section-default-codeowners.png -- Define default owners for CODEOWNERS sections]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_owners.html#set-default-owner-for-a-section) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/371711).

That way, you know owners are set by default, ensuring the approvers' assignment will always have a group to be referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a confusion in the previous answers here between

- *approvers*: the people that can click on 'Approve' to get the MR in a merge-able state. Potentially this list can be very long in a big company.
- *reviewers*: a (usually) much shorter list of people you're *asking* to review this MR.

As a further clarification, I guess that the OP would like to choose the reviewers in the pool of approvers.

The OP is asking if Gitlab provides a feature to auto-choose reviewers, given the approval rules that apply to the current MR. **Sadly, AFAIK, the answer is no**.

However, you might want to look at what Gitlab itself is doing internally: their job `danger-review` leverages a library `danger` (https://danger.systems/js/) to run their "Reviewer Roulette": a process that assigns reviewer to a given MR (but I don't know if they take approval rules into account when doing so)